# How prevent JLabel from appear 3 dots when text exceeds

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNWiq.png)

how preven jlabel from appear 3 dots when text size large?

Comment: Answer: don't make the text too large.

Comment: You can try using tags as - 


    `yourLabel.setText("<html><body><nobr>"+ inputString +"</nobr></body></html>");`

Though would probably suggest for a use case related to Calculator, you intend not to do so. Not sure if the dup link answers it in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to not use a JLabel and instead use a JTextArea with word-wrap and line-wrap turned on. You could then decorate the JTextArea to make it look like a JLabel (border, background color, etc.).

```
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
```